# Expansion of the Mittag-Leffler function $E_{s}(x^{s})$

Tags: complex-analysis, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

I want to find an expansion of the [Mittag-Leffler function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mittag-Leffler_function) $E_{s}(x^{s})$ of the form :
$$E_{s}(x^{s})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)g_{n}(s)\;\;\;\;\;(\Im(x)=\Im(s)=0)$$
I first defind the function $\Omega(x,s)$:
$$\Omega(x,s)=sE_{s}(x^{s})-s-(e^{x}-1)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{ns}}{n\Gamma(ns)}-\frac{x^{n}}{n!}$$
The reason for the introduction of the term $e^{x}-1$ is to extend the domain of convergence of the Laplace transform of $\Omega(x,s)$, which is given by :
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\Omega(x,s)e^{-zx}dx=\frac{s}{z(z^{s}-1)}-\frac{1}{z(z-1)}$$
Applying the Bromwich inversion formula, we obtain : 
$$\Omega(x,s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty}\left[\frac{s}{z(z^{s}-1)}-\frac{1}{z(z-1)}
\right ]e^{zx}dz\;\;\;\;(c>0)$$
Making the change of variables $z=e^{y}$, we obtain :
$$\Omega(x,s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\int_{\Gamma}\left(\frac{s}{e^{sy}-1}-\frac{1}{e^{y}-1} \right )e^{xe^{y}}dy$$
Where the path $\Gamma$ is the map from $\Re(z)=c\;$ by the log function. 
Using the fact that :
$$e^{x(e^{y}-1)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\phi_{n}(x)}{n!}y^{n}$$
$\phi_{n}(x)$ being the nth order [Bell polynomial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BellPolynomial.html)
We obtain :
$$\Omega(x,s)=\frac{1}{2\pi i }\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{x}\phi_{n}(x)}{n!}\int_{\Gamma}\left(\frac{s}{e^{sy}-1}-\frac{1}{e^{y}-1} \right )y^{n}dy
$$
Now, i am a bit confused on how to do the integrals above. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The Mittag-Leffler function depends on *two* complex parameters and the variable $z$, but I only see a single parameter $s$. What variation are you considering?

Comment: I am considering $E_{s,1}(x^{s})$ which for short i write as $E_{s}(x^{s})$. This is a function of two numbers $x\;$and $s$. For simplicity, i am taking the imaginary parts of the two numbers to be identically zero. The $z$ parameter appears in the Laplace transform of the modified function $\Omega(x,s)$ w.r.t. the real variable $x$.

Comment: What do you want to do from $E_{s}(x^{s})=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_{n}(x)g_{n}(s)$ ? $E_s(x) = \sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{x^{sk}}{\Gamma(sk+1)}=
 \sum_{k\ge 0} \frac{(\sum_{m \ge 0} \frac{(sk \log x)^m}{m!})}{\Gamma(sk+1)}
$ is already in the form you are asking.

Comment: i want to study the behavior of $E_{s}(x^{s})$ in the $s$ plane.